# code runs indefinitely while trying to send mail via python

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to send mail using python  via my own setup mail server

```
    import smtplib   
    SERVER='myserverdomain.com'
    server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER,587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(USER,PASS)
    server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
    server.quit()
```

But when I run the above code after line 3 it is not executing.Kind of like goes into an infinite loop.Why could this be

I am able to ping my server successfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import smtplib   
    SERVER='myserverdomain.com'
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(SERVER,587)
    server.login(USER,PASS)
    server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
    server.quit()
```

This answer worked